# How to make an animation controlled by scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, jsfiddle

Sorry for my poor English.

http://first-launch.com/ 
I want to know how to built an animation like the girl in this website.
I have found this demo.(Sorry, I don't konw how to post jsfiddle.)
jsfiddle.net/cc5712/es5zW/
But it can just control the animation by scroll.
Not like first-launch, when I scroll up, the girl's action will move back.

Is there any JQuery or javascript can make animation that is controlled by scroll?

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for parallaxing

http://www.webdesign.org/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website.22336.html

jquery plugin registry for parallaxing:
https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/parallax/

Comment: I'm not asking for parallaxing.
I'm asking for the girl's animation, like running. 
first-launch has used skrollr, and I think I know how to use it.
still thanks for your answer!